# "Unknown argument" when creating a model with angular-crud

Tags: angular, angular-cli, crud, angular-schematics

I'm trying to setup the package 'angular-crud' in my Angular 14 project.

Followed the README instructions at https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-crud, including creating a folder under src/app with the name of the model and copying a 'model.json' file under it.

Unfortunately when I try to generate a model I get

```
/> ng g angular-crud:crud-module person
Error: Unknown argument: person
```

Looks like a problem related to Angular Schematics and the CLI... maybe due to the version of Angular I'm using.

Any hint very appreciated.

Thomas

```
Angular CLI: 14.2.1
Node: 16.17.0
Package Manager: npm 8.15.0
OS: win32 x64

@angular-devkit/architect       0.1402.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular   14.2.1
@angular-devkit/core            14.2.1
@angular-devkit/schematics      14.2.1
@angular/cli                    14.2.1
@schematics/angular             14.2.1
rxjs                            7.4.0
typescript                      4.8.2

"angular-crud": "^3.0.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make the person model in model.json fist and put in your folder module (src/app/person) then run

```
ng g angular-crud:crud-module person
```

Comment: already did that, same error